# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on WP site

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

First post here. As noted in the title, I am getting the below error:

*Invalid argument supplied for foreach()*

Below is the offending code. I have tried contacting the theme's developer, but have received no response.

```
$categories = get_post_meta ( $post->ID, THEME_NAME."_content", true ); 
$cat = "";
$catCount = 0;
foreach($categories as $cat) {
    $cat.= $catID.",";
    $catCount++;
}
```

From what I have read, it appears that what the code is trying to grab is not actually an array, but I am not coder, so I am just guessing.

The code is the beginning of a dropdown that is populated with all of the Post categories that, when each is clicked, adjusts a filterable grid.

I hope this is enough to get going. If more info is needed, let me know.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: below is the full code for that section:

```
<?php 
    wp_reset_query();
    global $post;


    $categories = get_post_meta ( $post->ID, THEME_NAME."_content", true ); 
    $cat = "";
    $catCount = 0;
    foreach($categories as $cat) {
        $cat.= $catID.",";
        $catCount++;
    }


    $count = get_post_meta ( $post->ID, THEME_NAME."_home_post_count", true ); 
    if(!$count) $count = 5;

    $paged = get_query_string_paged();
    $args=array(
        'cat' => $cat,
        'post_type'=>"post",
        'ignore_sticky_posts'=>1,
        'posts_per_page' => $count,
        'paged'=>$paged
    );

    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    $counter = 1;


?>
```

Comment: What does get_post_meta() return?

Comment: Put an "if(is_array($categories)) {" before and a "}" after your foreach loop.

Comment: Don't see `$catID` declared.

Comment: I added the "if" above, and it removed the error, so most likely it is not written correctly.

Comment: added full original code above

Comment: Do `var_dump( $categories );` immediately after setting the variable and just before your `foreach` loop. I'm almost definitely sure you are getting an empty value or a string and not a valid array of values